# Hiding/unhiding with input controls Webi BusinessObjects

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

I have a variable `Hide` set to "true" so a table is automatically hidden. I would like to set this variable to "false" when an input control is chosen so the table is unhidden. Is there a way to do this?

Update:

I got the following code to work if specific input is hardcoded in code but I would like it to return false if ANY input control or report filter is selected.

```
=If ReportFilter([x])="Joe" Then "false" Else "true"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved my issue. I have set a dimension called "hide" to `=If Match(ReportFilter([x]);"*;*")Then "true" Else "false"` I then set the table to unhide when "hide" = false

What this does is once a filter is added with an input control, the filter will no longer include a ";" and the table will be unhidden